# stripe API - possible to combine multiple invoices into one payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

i have a use case where its possible for a user to accumulate multiple unpaid invoices with a stripe subscription (which would be marked as overdue). The only way i see to pay the invoices via the API would be to pay each one as a separate manual invoice payment (thus producing X lines items on a users credit card).

Is there any way to combine all unpaid invoices into one payment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not something that the Stripe API supports. The best solution would be to create a one-time [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) for the total amount of all the invoices and then mark each invoice as [forgiven](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_invoice-forgiven).

You could also create multiple [invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem), one for each invoice with a clear description and amount and then invoice the list so that your customer knows what he's paying for.

Answer (score 1):

From the Stripe docs, it suggests that you can batch multiple transactions together but only if the customer has a payment method saved (and it still may require some custom programming to get it working the way you want):
https://support.stripe.com/questions/batch-multiple-transactions-from-one-customer-into-a-single-charge

Stripe docs also offers this option as well, on combining multiple products into one subscription:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can combine multiple invoices using pass stripe customer id in to

/Stripe/Invoices::retrieve({customer_id});

You can get all the invoice of the customer, you can also search date wise invoices using a function.

Comment: I do not believe this answers the question... This would retrieve all the customers invoices, but does not allow a single payment from customer to pay all oustanding invoices at once.